# Use for loop to fill the fields

Tags: java

so first here is my code :

```
public class eol {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String x = "Charles.Baudelaire*05051988*France Sergei.Esenin*01011968*Russia Herman.Hesse*23051996*Germany";

   String[] word= x.split("[.,*, ]");
    for(int i=0;i<word.length;i++){
       // System.out.print(word[i]+" ");
    }
    String name = word[0];
    String lastname = word[1];
    String dod =word[2];
    String cob= word[3];

    System.out.print("First person data : "+
            "\n"+ name +" "+ "\n"+lastname+" "+"\n"+ dod+" "+"\n"+ cob);
```

I want to loop through string x, and take needed values, and use them to make 3 objects of class writer, is there any way i do this with for loop ? 
Or would i have to "break" original string in 3 smaller arrays, then do for loop for every one of them.

I mean, i can use for loop to print out data on screen, by incrementing counter by certain value, how ever to add these data to fields is something I don't understand how to do.

Comment: where is you class Writer? You need to think about your string as a list of writers, and then first 'brake' the string based on that. How many writer are in that string? So how would you iterate through that string if there is dynamic list of writer - yes in a loop, and for each writer in a loop you can parse you substring to create Writer object. You will probably want to store those writer in some other kind of list?

Comment: Why not first split by space " "? Then you would get an array with every author: ``String[] authors= x.split(" ");`` It's much easier to understand and can avoid errors.

Comment: @teddy3D yea, that is idea i also had, then i will have array, or arraylist with autors, how ever after that i also must split them again to get each individual data. Because if i split by space, my first index in "authors" will be Charles.Baudelaire*05051988*France, which then i must again "break" in to smaller parts. but thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You can do the following:

```
Validate.isTrue(word.length % 4 == 0, "Array size must be a multiple of 4");
List<Writer> writers = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0; i<word.length; i+=4) {
    String name = word[i];
    String lastname = word[i+1];
    String dod =word[i+2];
    String cob= word[i+3];
    writers.add(new Writer(name, lastname, dod, cob));
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend this answer because of a possible ``ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException``. In my opinion it's better to split the input in authors and then in author details. It's a little bit more code but more safe to use.

Comment: I didn't perform full user-input validation because that's not relevant to the question being asked. But since you've brought it up, I've edited the answer to check for valid array lengths.

Comment: The documentation says it should be ``Validate.isTrue``. Still no solution I would use in production but it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`i += 4` instead of `i++` after each tern of loop, and use `word[i]`, `word[i+1]`, `word[i+2]` and `word[i+3]` in loop.

i.e.

```
String x = "Charles.Baudelaire*05051988*France Sergei.Esenin*01011968*Russia Herman.Hesse*23051996*Germany";

String[] word= x.split("[.,*, ]");
for(int i=0;i<word.length;i+=4){
    String name = word[i];
    String lastname = word[i+1];
    String dod =word[i+2];
    String cob= word[i+3];
    // Use these variable.
}
```